# How I get the Parametervalue of a xml for the treeview`?

Tags: c#, xml, parsing, treeview, treeviewitem

hi i have a xml and i want it show in my treeview in C#

it works but the treeview don't show me the what i want see.

i try to explain my  problem:

here is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LM-X STAT_VERSION="3.32">
<LICENSE_PATH TYPE="NETWORK" HOST="6200@lwserv005" SERVER_VERSION="4.4.4" UPTIME="53 day(s) 21 hour(s) 10 min(s) 50 sec(s)">
FEATURE NAME="GlobalZoneEU" VERSION="12.0" VENDOR="ALTAIR" START="2013-03-26" END="2014-03-31" USED_LICENSES="111720" TOTAL_LICENSES="147000" SHARE="CUSTOM ,VIRTUAL">
<USER NAME="SYSTEM" HOST="LWSERV171" IP="172.16.11.115" USED_LICENSES="2000" LOGIN_TIME="2013-04-17 12:42" CHECKOUT_TIME="2013-04-17 12:42" SHARE_CUSTOM="hweuser:172.16.11.115"/>
...
</LICENSE_PATH>
</LM-X>
```

I want in my treeview a structure how this: This are FEATUREs

GlobalZoneEU
HWAIFPBS
HWAWPF
...

here is my c# code:

```
private void btnShowLicstate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string command = "\"C:\\lmxendutil.exe\" -licstatxml -host lwserv005 -port 6200";

    string output = ExecuteCommand(command);
    string final_output = output.Substring(90, output.Length-90);

    XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(final_output);

    BuildTree(treeLic, doc); 


    txtOutput.Text = final_output; 
}

static string ExecuteCommand(string command)
{
    int exitCode;
    ProcessStartInfo processInfo;
    Process process;

    processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/c " + command);
    processInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    processInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    processInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

    process = Process.Start(processInfo);

    string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    exitCode = process.ExitCode;

    process.Close();

    return output; 
}

private void BuildTree(TreeView treeView, XDocument doc)
{
    TreeNode treeNode = new TreeNode(doc.Root.Name.LocalName);
    treeView.Nodes.Add(treeNode);
    BuildNodes(treeNode, doc.Root);
}

private void BuildNodes(TreeNode treeNode, XElement element)
{
    foreach (XNode child in element.Nodes())
    {
        switch (child.NodeType)
        {
            case XmlNodeType.Element:
                XElement childElement = child as XElement;
                TreeNode childTreeNode = new TreeNode(childElement.Name.LocalName);
                treeNode.Nodes.Add(childTreeNode);
                BuildNodes(childTreeNode, childElement);
                break;
            case XmlNodeType.Text:
                XText childText = child as XText;
                treeNode.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(childText.Value));
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

How I can get the names of the nodes for example--->

```
<FEATURE NAME="GlobalZoneEU" VERSION="12.0" VENDOR="ALTAIR"  ...>
```

I want only NAME ...

Answer (score 1):

Not *entirely* sure what you want, but are you looking for

```
(string)childElement.Attributes("NAME")
```

instead of

```
childElement.Name.LocalName
```

?